# Component not rendering in simple React.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to get a simple "Hello, World"-type **React.js app** from the book [*React and React Native*](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/react-and-react-native) running under Node/webpack-dev-server. I'm not seeing any errors, but **the page is blank when I visit it in my browser**.

Here's how I tried—and failed—to run the book's [very first example](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/React-and-React-Native/tree/master/Chapter02/hello-jsx):

1. Install `node` and `npm` using these steps (adapted from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814)):

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/.local/node-latest-install
   $ cd ~/.local/node-latest-install
   $ curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
   $ ./configure --prefix=~/.local
   $ make -j install
   $ curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
   $ node -v; npm -v
   v7.7.4
   4.1.2
   ```
2. Clone the examples repo from the book:

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/PacktPublishing/React-and-React-Native.git
   ```
3. Run `npm install` from the top-level examples folder:

   ```
   $ cd React-and-React-Native
   $ npm install
   ```
4. Attempt to compile/run `hello-jsx` example:

   ```
   $ cd Chapter02/hello-jsx
   $ node ../../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
   ...
   ERROR in ./main.js
   Module build failed: Error: React Hot Loader: The Webpack loader is now exported separately. If you use Babel, we recommend that you remove "react-hot-loader" from the "loaders" section of your Webpack configuration altogether, and instead add "react-hot-loader/babel" to the "plugins" section of your .babelrc file. If you prefer not to use Babel, replace "react-hot-loader" or "react-hot" with "react-hot-loader/webpack" in the "loaders" section of your Webpack configuration.
   at Object.warnAboutIncorrectUsage (/home/evadeflow/.local/React-and-React-Native/node_modules/react-hot-loader/lib/index.js:7:11)
   @ multi main
   webpack: Failed to compile.
   ```
5. Edit `hello-jsx/webpack.config.js` to work around the above error:

   ```
   diff --git a/Chapter02/hello-jsx/webpack.config.js b/Chapter02/hello-jsx/webpack.config.js
   index 312f152..592e767 100644
   --- a/Chapter02/hello-jsx/webpack.config.js
   +++ b/Chapter02/hello-jsx/webpack.config.js
   @@ -13,7 +13,7 @@ module.exports = {
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
   -        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=es2015'],
   +        loaders: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'babel?presets[]=es2015'],
          },
        ],
      },
   ```
6. Recompile/re-run:

   ```
   $ node ../../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
   http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/  
   webpack result is served from /
   content is served from /home/evadeflow/.local/React-and-React-Native/Chapter02/hello-jsx
   Hash: 590282c761dccbb5710a
   Version: webpack 1.14.0
   Time: 1260ms
            Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   main-bundle.js  978 kB       0  [emitted]  main 
   chunk    {0} main-bundle.js (main) 923 kB [rendered]
       [0] multi main 52 bytes {0} [built]
       [1] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 3.97 kB {0} [built]
       [2] /home/evadeflow/.local/React-and-React-Native/~/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
       [3] /home/evadeflow/.local/React-and-React-Native/~/url/~/punycode/punycode.js 14.6 kB {0} [built]

     <... lots of similar output omitted ...>

     [251] /home/evadeflow/.local/React-and-React-Native/~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js 4.32 kB {0} [built]
     [252] /home/evadeflow/.local/React-and-React-Native/~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropHook.js 1.37 kB {0} [built]
     [253] /home/evadeflow/.local/React-and-React-Native/~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMInvalidARIAHook.js 3.14 kB {0} [built]
   webpack: Compiled successfully.
   ```

After the last step, `node` is running. However, I see a blank page when I hit `localhost:8080` in my browser:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have any console errors in your `localhost:8080` page? If so, can you share them with us?

Comment: The only items in the console are: `Error: The document content type is not HTML : undefined`, followed by `Result: 0 errors / 0 warnings` and `Info: W3c Online Validation`.

Comment: That's a weird one. I poked around on the repo and it feels like it should run...but alas it's probably another victim of JavaScript's transpiler hell. If you're interested, i can point you to some other resources that helped me learn react.

Comment: "Error: The document content type is not HTML : undefined" are you setting `<!DOCTYPE>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1) Install webpack both globally and locally, i.e. at the base directory of the code do the following:

```
npm install webpack --global
npm install webpack --save-dev
```

2) Install the webpack dev server, also both globally and locally:

```
npm install webpack-dev-server --global
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

3) Update the webpack.config.js files, in particular the "loader" line, as follows:

(A) Replace 'react-hot' with 'react-hot-loader/webpack'

(B) Replace 'babel' with 'babel-loader'

So for example, the "hello-jsx" file here is the line in the OLD, ORIGINAL webpack.config.js file:

```
loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=es2015'],
```

And here is the line in the NEW, UPDATE webpack.config.js file:

```
loaders: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015'],
```

4) Run the webpack dev server (from the subdirectory) with the hot and inline options, e.g.

```
$ pwd
[whatever_base_directory]/Chapter02/hello-jsx
$ webpack-dev-server --hot --inline
```

Comment: Wow. Your answer helped me figure out how to run the examples—thank you! It turns out, though, that adding the `--hot` option to my `webpack-dev-server` invocation was sufficient: `node ../../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --hot`. I'm definitely going to accept your answer, but perhaps you could delete the part about installing `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` globally? For me, it works with or without `--inline`. (I'm omitting it for now, since I don't know what it does.)

Comment: Also, it seems that simply changing `react-hot` to `react-hot-loader/webpack` is sufficient. Your patch to `webpack.config.js` may be 'better' than mine (i.e., using `'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015'],` instead of `'babel?presets[]=es2015'],`), though, so perhaps that should remain in your answer. (I remember seeing an error message at some point saying that `babel-loader` is now preferred, but I can't recall where.) .In any case... just wanted to leave a note for posterity that adding `--hot` to my `webpack-dev-server` invocation was the *minimum* addition for the steps in my question to work.

Comment: On the babel loader, check the browser console and see if it is giving an error or warning, if not you may be good but if so may need to make that change as well.

Comment: Also on installing the dev server globally...once I did that then all I needed to do was run the webpack-dev-sever command from each project directory and it would run that project within a chapter, i.e. I still used the hot and inline options but I don't need to give the full path (e.g. ../../node_modules/etc.)...nice to be able to just go to any subdirectory and type the same, simple "webpack-dev-sever" command.

Comment: Omitting `--inline` didn't result in any console errors, so I'll continue to leave it out for now, until I fully understand how it works and what (if any) additional entries may be needed in `webpack.config.js` to fully take advantage of webpack's [HMR](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hmr-react/) feature with React. (The [webpack-dev-server docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-inline-cli-only) imply that using `--inline` with `--hot` is *recommended*, so that's probably a sensible combination, in general.)

Comment: **UPDATE**: In case any other non-webdevs stumble upon this post, I just observed that passing `--inline` (in addition to `--hot`) makes hot reloading work without any need to manually refresh the browser. I just edited my source file, and the browser refreshed automatically. I was only mildly annoyed that I had to click *Refresh* before, but using `--inline` is clearly a [even] better solution, so... I'll definitely be making that a habit.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved a lot of these issues. Try pulling the [latest](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/React-and-React-Native).

The two major things I've fixed are:

1. Using Webpack 2 as a dependency and adding instructions for installing webpack/webpack-dev-server globally as part of the initial setup.
2. Simplified webpack configuration for each example. We only need babel-loader and one entry point.

Give it a try, let me know if it's any easier to get going.

Comment: *Yes*, thank you, Adam, everything is working fine now, thanks for the quick turnaround. Really enjoying the book so far...

Comment: Super. Keep the feedback coming.